# Session not working - PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm having some problems with sessions in PHP. Before, i have a website, and not i'm improving the layout. I tought it would be easy, but a lot of things changed. For example:
Before i was declaring a variable like `$Variable = $_SESSION['test'];` and was working perfectly, even without condicionals with issets. Now, it says that the variable is not declared.

Well, this is just for information. My problem is with the login session. I'm trying to make a function to verify if the user is logged or not (if not, the user will be "anonymous".

This is the .php file thats makes the user logged. It works with a JQuery script, just to not refresh the page.

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inclusoes/Conexao.php');
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/Funcoes.php');
$Funcoes = new Funcoes();

$Login = $_POST['dado_login'];
$Senha = $_POST['dado_senha'];
$Mensagem = array();

if (empty($_POST['dado_login']))
  $Mensagem[] = "<img src='../imgs/Error.png'><span style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'> Please, enter username.</span>";

elseif (empty($_POST['dado_senha']))
  $Mensagem[] = "<img src='../imgs/Error.png'><span style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'> Please, enter password.</span>";

$countError = count($Mensagem);

    if($countError > 0)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$countError;$i++)
          /*echo ucwords($Mensagem[$i]) . ' ';*/
          echo $Mensagem[$i];
    }
    else
    {
      $Query = "SELECT id_usuario, nick, senha FROM usuarios WHERE nick = '$Login' && senha = '$Senha'";
//        $LoginCorreto = mysql_query($Query, $conexao) or die (mysql_error());
      $LoginCorreto = $Funcoes->MySQLError($Query, $conexao);
      $ChecarUsuario = mysql_num_rows($LoginCorreto);

        if ($ChecarUsuario > 0)
        {
          $_SESSION["sessionUsuario"] = $Login;
          echo 'Correct';
        }
        else
        {
          echo "<img src='../imgs/Error.png'><span style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'> Login failed. Please, try again.</span>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is function, very simple.

```
    function isLogado()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuarioSession']))
      return false;
    else
      return true;
}
```

And here is what i'm doing

```
include ('functions.php');
$Funcoes = new Funcoes();

if (!$Funcoes->isLogado)
  *show the login form*
else
  *welcome, User!*
```

The session is ALWAYS empty, or not set. If you 'echo' the session, it will not show anything. Before i was just writting `$Variable = $_SESSION['test']` and no errors happened, never.

How to solve it? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Where is your session_start();

Comment: Each page you want to use `$_SESSION` needs to use `session_start();`

Comment: And if  even you can't find session_start then that is the problem right there

Comment: "Before i was just writting "$Variable = $_SESSION['test'] and no errors happened, never." - this means that you were relying on problem behaviour of the old PHP version. Now they've fixed at least some issues, so your code won't work anymore, as it was never done properly. It sounds like you've been working with very old PHP version before.